# How to reuse code inside another spec.js?

Tags: cypress

I have two test scripts that must be called by a third one. I don't would like to replicate the code for all test cases that uses the same two scripts and do many other things after.

I tried to use the **require** command but it seems to be ignored and the code after it is executed, skipping the intended script **AbrirNavegador.spec.js**

```
before(function() {require('./AbrirNavegador.spec.js')});
```

There's no information about error or something else. It's just skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never got that to work. But I do use another work around. What I do:

```js
// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('reuseMethod1', function({
  // first set of steps that need to be reused
})
Cypress.Commands.add('reuseMethod2', function({
  // second set of steps that need to be reused
})
```

```js
// testscript_1.js
cy.reuseMethod1()
```

```js
// testscript_2.js
cy.reuseMethod1()
cy.reuseMethod2()
```

You can call the methods at any place, so also in a before/beforeEach/after/afterEach. So the only code duplication you have is the part of calling the method.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.J. I appreciate your prompt reply. I'm newbie using Cypress. Can I include all lines of my script replacing // first set of steps that need to be reused? Including cy.get, cy.visit and so on? It must be inside command.js, right? Thanks, again

Comment: nope you can use every line you normally would. The only exceptions are the context lines like `describe()`, `before()`, `after()`, `context()` and `it()`. Besides that there are no limitations. You can put it in the commands.js. But you can also choose to split it up to for example testx.js. If you decide to do that you have to put the line `import './testx.js` in the index.js file (it is in the same directory as the commands.js)

Comment: you might want to accept the answer. It helps keeping stackoverflow clean.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: By clicking the arrow up in front of my answer (You'll see a big number '0' with an up and down arrow. If someone gives an bad answer you can also down vote the answer)